# Want a fix image at the end of screen

Tags: iphone, ios, image, xcode4, uitableview

I am creating an iPhone app. I am using `UITableViewController` for displaying my contents. I want to display image at end of my table or i can say at the end of iPhone screen. The image would be static. It can't be scroll with table view.

So , How can this possible in `UITableViewController`? or it can only work with `UIViewController`?

Thank you in advance..!!

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by using UIViewController. Use UIView with ImageView and TableView embeded in it. Place ImageView at the bottom(which you can make staic) and then place TableView at the top (which you can make scrollable).

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you should have a UIView with your image at the bottom and then a scrolling UITableView embedded into it (and underneath the bottom image).